# Подготовка данных для обучения нейросети

Tags: python, numpy, keras

Подготавливаю тренировочные и тестовые данные для обучения модели автокодировщика. При изменении данных одним способом, модель видит тренировочные данные, но не воспринимает тестовые (постоянно val loss >= 20% при train loss < 1%). В скрипте изменил только небольшой кусок кода, все стало работать как надо. Но где ошибка в первом варианте, понять не могу.
Надоумьте, кто понимает.

```
# Для работы с тензорами
import numpy as np

# Класс создания модели
from keras.models import Model

# Для загрузки данных
from keras.datasets import mnist
from random import randint
from keras import utils


(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = X_train.astype('float32')/255.
x_test = X_test.astype('float32')/255.

y_train = np.copy(x_train)
y_test = np.copy(x_test)
y_train = y_train.reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
y_test = y_test.reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
```

Первый вариант продолжения, который не срабатывает:

```
def get_squares(temp_array:np.array):
    ch_array = np.copy(temp_array)
    height = ch_array.shape[1]
    width = ch_array.shape[2]
    x = randint(0, width - 8 - 1)
    y = randint(0, height - 8 - 1)
    for pict in range(0, ch_array.shape[0]):
        for temp_x in range(x, x + 8):
            for temp_y in range(y, y + 8):
                ch_array[pict, temp_y, temp_x] = 0
    return ch_array

x_train_noise = get_squares(x_train).reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
x_test_noise = get_squares(x_test).reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
```

Второй рабочий вариант:

```
def add_square(x):
  x = x.copy()
  # Создаем координату Х квадрата
  squareRandomX = np.random.randint(20)

  # Создаем координату Y квадрата
  squareRandomY = np.random.randint(20)

  # Закрашивание черным пикселей в рамках квадрата
  for i in range(squareRandomX,squareRandomX+8):
    for j in range(squareRandomY,squareRandomY+8):
         x[i,j] = 0

  return x

# вставка квадратов
x_train_noise = x_train.reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))
x_test_noise = x_test.reshape((-1, 28, 28, 1))

x_train_noise = np.array(list(map(add_square, x_train_noise)))
x_test_noise = np.array(list(map(add_square, x_test_noise)))
```